# How to add active state to tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I started learning React Native for 2 weeks. In parallel with learning I try to develop what I want to learn, small things.

I created navigation tabs, but not with router, only with state. I tried for last 3 days to figure out how to put active class on each tab, to see that when I click on each tab that the active one has a different color.

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import Gator from "./Gator";
import Croco from "./Croco";
import Style from "./Style";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0
  };

  getTab = index => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return <Gator />;
      case 1:
        return <Croco />;
      case 2:
        return <Style />;
      default:
        return <Croco />;
    }
  };

  setIndex(int) {
    this.setState({ index: int });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <View style={style.tabsWrapper}>
          <View style={style.tabsContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setIndex(0)}>
              <View style={style.tabItem}>
                <Text style={[style.tabText]}>Croco</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setIndex(1)}>
              <View style={style.tabItem}>
                <Text style={[style.tabText]}>Gator</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setIndex(2)}>
              <View style={style.tabItem}>
                <Text style={[style.tabText]}>Style</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View>{this.getTab(this.state.index)}</View>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  tabsWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: "#eeeeee",
    width: "100%",
    height: "5%",
    borderBottomColor: "#cccccc",
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  tabsContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    // margin: 30,
    // marginTop: 10,
    padding: 5,
    paddingTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    height: "20%"
  },
  tabItem: {
    alignItems: "center"
  },

  tabText: {
    fontFamily: "DINRoundPro-Bold",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#aaaaaa"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Each other components, that are for each tab, are just with some text to show on the screen.

I test it online, so you can see it on [react native sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-cve43).

Can someone please help me with this situation?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to highlight the selected tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [conditionally add a class](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html) to make your `Tab` active, like this `style={[ style.tabText, this.state.index===0 && style.activeTabText ]}`

```
<View style={style.tabsContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setIndex(0)}>
        <View style={style.tabItem}>
            <Text style={[ style.tabText, this.state.index===0 && style.activeTabText ]}>
                Croco
            </Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setIndex(1)}>
        <View style={style.tabItem}>
            <Text style={[ style.tabText, this.state.index===1 && style.activeTabText ]}>
                Gator
            </Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.setIndex(2)}>
        <View style={style.tabItem}>
            <Text style={[ style.tabText, this.state.index===2 && style.activeTabText ]}>
                Style
            </Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

And add style like,

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({

  ...

  activeTabText: {
    color: "red",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a code to solve the problem. Use the status value to obtain and change parameters.

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import Gator from "./Gator";
import Croco from "./Croco";
import Style from "./Style";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    backcolor: "",
    backcolor2:"",
    backcolor3:""
  };

  getTab = index => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return <Gator />;
      case 1:
        return <Croco />;
      case 2:
        return <Style />;
      default:
        return <Croco />;
    }
  };
  setIndex(int) {
    this.setState({ index: int });
    this.backcolor(int)
  }

  backcolor(int) {
    if (int === 0) {
      this.setState({
        backcolor : "red",
        backcolor2:"",
        backcolor3:""
      })
    } else if(int === 1){
      this.setState({
        backcolor : "",
        backcolor2:"red",
        backcolor3:""
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        backcolor : "",
        backcolor2:"",
        backcolor3:"red"
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <View style={style.tabsWrapper}>
          <View style={style.tabsContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.setIndex(0)}
              style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backcolor}}
            >
              <View style={style.tabItem}>
                <Text style={[style.tabText]} color="red">
                  Croco
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setIndex(1)} 
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backcolor2}}>
              <View style={style.tabItem}>
                <Text style={[style.tabText]}>Gator</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setIndex(2)}
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backcolor3}}>
              <View style={style.tabItem}>
                <Text style={[style.tabText]}>Style</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View>{this.getTab(this.state.index)}</View>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  tabsWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: "#eeeeee",
    width: "100%",
    height: "5%",
    borderBottomColor: "#cccccc",
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  tabsContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    // margin: 30,
    // marginTop: 10,
    padding: 5,
    paddingTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    height: "20%"
  },
  tabItem: {
    alignItems: "center"
  },

  tabText: {
    fontFamily: "DINRoundPro-Bold",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#aaaaaa"
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write `setIndex = (int) => {` instead of `setIndex(int) {` because or else your function is not bind to your component.